# use AesCryptoServiceProvider to Decrypt without IV

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes

I have written a BlackBerry app that uses AES encryption. I am trying to decrypt this using the AesCryptoServiceProvider in C#.

The BlackBerry code doesn't seem to use an IV which means I have nothing to pass to the AesCryptoServiceProvider.

Is it possible for me to decrypt AES without an IV, if so, how?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#.NET " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Ok, I will try Zeroes and report back. Thanks for the reminder John, I often wonder are my titles ok.

Comment: Hmm, I've just tried all zeros and it doesn't complain. Thanks. My message is still coming out as garbage though. I think there is an issue with padding coming from the data. I've been told PKCS#7 is the same as PKCS#5 but .NET doesn't seem to think so. It's giving "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed"

Comment: If your message is all garbage (multiple blocks) then your key or cipher text (encoding) is incorrect. If it was the IV, only the first block would be garbled. If it is the padding, the decrypt should fail (or a raw decrypt would show the wrong padding bytes).

Comment: You'll really have to dig up the specs for the blackberry lib. Too many settings and possibilities.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I just figured it out. It turned out to be a property in AesCryptoServiceProvider called Mode. Should be set to CipherMode.ECB

Comment: It should also be noted that using a block cipher like AES in ECB mode is highly discouraged.  There are many attacks that work against the security and data integrity of ECB mode.  Proceed with caution.

Comment: Thank you. This is for a college project and time is running out on me so unfortunately I have to stick with ECB. I will be sure to mention research the vulnerability and mention it in my report. Thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: @conor: ECB mode does not require an IV, it should decrypt correctly without having one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the blackberry java crypto documentation, it appears you are not supposed to directly use AESEncryptionEngine. If you use it straight, you end up with ( I assume) ECB mode which results in the following encryption of an image of a  penguin. don't do it.

[image: Bad Encryption]
Rather it  appears that to use some secure mode of operation, you need to actually use a wrapper around the basic AESEncrypt / Decrypt Engine. You want to use the [CBCEncryptionEngine](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/CBCEncryptorEngine.html) to do this. Here is some sample code from [here](http://view-source:http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/doc-files/CryptoTest.html#sampleDESCBCEncryption). Note that the IV is randomized on creation, so you don't need to set it or worry about reuse. Just replace DES with AES here.

```
// sampleDESCBCEncryption
private static int sampleDESCBCEncryption( 
    byte[] secretKey, byte[] initVector, byte[] plainText, byte[] cipherText, int
    dataLength ) 
    throws CryptoException, IOException
{
    // Create a new DES key based on the 8 bytes in the secretKey array
    DESKey key = new DESKey( secretKey );

    // Create a new initialization vector using the 8 bytes in initVector
    InitializationVector iv = new InitializationVector( initVector );

    // Create a new byte array output stream for use in encryption
    NoCopyByteArrayOutputStream out = new NoCopyByteArrayOutputStream();

    // Create a new instance of a BlockEncryptor passing in an instance of a CBC encryptor engine
    // (containing an instance of a DES encryptor engine), the initialization vector, and the
    // output stream
    BlockEncryptor cryptoStream = new BlockEncryptor( 
        new CBCEncryptorEngine( new DESEncryptorEngine( key ), iv ), out );

    // Write dataLength bytes from plainText to the CFB encryptor stream
    cryptoStream.write( plainText, 0, dataLength );
    cryptoStream.close();

    // Now copy the encrypted bytes from out into cipherText and return the length
    int finalLength = out.size();
    System.arraycopy( out.getByteArray(), 0, cipherText, 0, finalLength );
    return finalLength;
}
```